# A react form doesn't capture input into a formik fieldarray

Tags: arrays, reactjs, field, formik

I send pieces of code that involve a field array in formik, the issue is the following: on the one hand the buttons to add and delete fields work correctly, on the other hand the text boxes
they work since you can enter data in them but when
the form is submitted, this data entered in the text boxes contained in a fieldarray is not sent, thanks for now.

Initial values of the form

```
  const formik = useFormik({
        initialValues: {
            no_doc: '',
            apellido: '',
            nombre: '',
            fec_nac: '',
            sexo: '',
            domicilio: '',
            no_tel: '',
            email: '',
            obra_soc: '',
            no_obra_soc: '',
            plan_obra_soc: '',
            fec_prot: Date.now.toString(),
            medico: '',
            diagnostico: '',
            medicacion: '',
            practicas_solicitadas: '',
            practica_s: [
                {
                cod_ana: '',
                autorizada: '',
                obra_soc:''
            }]
        },
       
        onSubmit: (data) => {
           // setFormData(data);
            setShowMessage(true);
            console.log(data);
            formik.resetForm();
        }

    });
```

Formik FieldArray code

```
 <FormikProvider value={formik}>
    <FieldArray name='practica_s'>
       {({push, remove, Formik }) => (
          <React.Fragment>
              {formik.values.practica_s.map(( practica_s , index) => (
                   <Grid container item>
                       <Grid item>
                            <Field name={`practica_s[${index}].cod_ana`}
                                   id="practica_s.cod_ana"
                                   component= {Autocomplete}
                                   sx={{ width: 300 }}
                                   autoHighlight    
                                   value= {practicas.cod_ana}
                                   options={practicas}        
                                   getOptionLabel={(option) => option.nom_ana}
                                   renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} label="Practica" />}/>
                        </Grid>
                             <Grid item>
                                 <Field name={`practica_s[${index}].autorizada`} 
                                 id="autorizada"
                                 component= {TextField}
                                 label= "Autorizada ?" />
                             </Grid>
                            <Grid item>
                                <Field name={`practica_s[${index}].obra_soc`} 
                                       id="obra_soc"
                                       component= {TextField}
                                       label= "Obra Social" />
                         </Grid>
                             <Grid item>
                                <Button  onClick={() => remove(index)}>Delete</Button>
                             </Grid>
                         </Grid>
             ))}
                            <Grid item>
                                <Button type='button' onClick={() => push({cod_ana:'', autorizacion:'', obra_soc:''})}>Add</Button>
                            </Grid>
        </React.Fragment>
    )}
  </FieldArray>
</FormikProvider>
```

Comment: I build a CodeSandBox with your code and I think the problem is with the components you're passing to the Field property. 

Just by commenting those, it works fine. Can you post the code from your <TextField/> component?  
CodeSandBox link => https://codesandbox.io/s/determined-meitner-hpo1q?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Also, noticed you're missing the key in <Grid container item> after the .map(). Try adding that one too.

Comment: Yes, the problem is definitely in the submitted component, I have already understood how to deal with simple elements like input text, now I should understand how to work with autocomplete fields and pass the data to the formik form, I think the key is in the renderInput option Any ideas? Thanks again.

Comment: Easy. You can use useFormikContext() and useField() to create your own custom fields. 

I updated the CodeSand box, with a custom Searchable component. Using react-select. 

Check it out, and let me know if I can help you.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, thanks to the help of @Thremulant, I was able to reformulate the "Fieldarray code" so that everything works.
Basically, at the Field the "component" option has been changed to the "as" option.
On the other hand I rewrote the code of the "Autocomplete" field so that when the selection is changed, a different value can be passed to the "Field" of FieldArray  than the one that the select shows, I await comments and thanks in advance for the help provided

```
<FormikProvider value={formik}>
  <FieldArray name='practica_s'>
    {({push, remove, Formik }) => (
      <React.Fragment>
        {formik.values.practica_s.map(( practica_s , index) => (
        <>
          <div className="p-col-12 p-md-3">
            <Autocomplete
              id="practicas"
              name="practicas"
              options={practicas}
              getOptionLabel={option => option.nom_ana}
              onChange={(e, value) => {
                formik.setFieldValue(`practica_s[${index}].cod_ana` , value.cod_ana)
                }}
              renderInput={params => (<TextField {...params}
                              name={`practica_s[${index}].autorizada`}  
                              label="Prtacticas"
                              variant="outlined"
                               />
              )}
              />
              </div>
              <div className="p-col-12 p-md-3">
                <div className="p-inputgroup">
                    <Field name={`practica_s[${index}].autorizada`} 
                       id="autorizada"
                       as= {InputText}
                       label= "Autorizada ?" />
                 </div>
               </div>
               <div className="p-col-12 p-md-3">
                 <div className="p-inputgroup">
                     <Field name={`practica_s[${index}].obra_soc`} 
                         id="obra_soc"
                         as= {InputText}
                         label= "Obra Social" />
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div className="p-col-12 p-md-3">
                    <Button  onClick={() => remove(index)}>Delete</Button>
                 </div>
      </>
     ))}
        <div className="p-col-12 ">
          <Button type='button' onClick={() => push({cod_ana:'', autorizada:'', obra_soc:''})}>Add</Button>
         </div>
   </React.Fragment>
   )}
 </FieldArray>
</FormikProvider>
```

Comment: Did you manage to set a default value to the autocomplete?